# Android using device art generator for screenshots

Tags: android, graphics, google-play, screenshot

Hello I've searched and was unable to find any information on this,

On the device art generator page there is a note saying 'Do not use graphics created here in store listing screen shots'

However nearly every app I see in the play store has screenshots wrapped in device art. Are these from another source? Has anyone had their app removed for using googles device art?

Comment: They say: `This provides better visual context for your app screenshots on your website or in other promotional materials`, but they don't want it **on the store**.

Comment: Right, but nearly every app has it in their listing. Are they from another source? Or does google not really care?

Comment: I really have no clue about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a request from Google, not a rule as such. So you can go ahead and use them in the play store listing of your app. I have myself discussed this earlier with many experienced folks.